# How to create spaces in star program?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to create a figure that will look like this. So I'm only able to get the right part and I have no idea how to implement the left part. Is there a way with loops to add spaces ever n-1 so I can make this desired figure?

```
*** *
** **
* ***
****

public class tuna {
   public static void potpie(int n){
     int i,j,k;
     for(i=1; i <= n; i++) {
        for(k=0;k<=n-i;k++) {
           System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(j=n;j>=k;j--) {
           System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that figure is correct? It has a discontinuity between the third and fourth rows.

Comment: Is No. of stars per row is same? Ex: In current figure its 4.

Comment: Yeah int n is amount of stars.

Comment: the figure is correct ;p;

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the last line in your example should be the first one. Assuming I'm right, this could get you going:

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int n=4;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            int j = n-i;
            System.out.println(times(j)+" "+times(i));
        }
    }

    private static String times(int n) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            sb.append("*");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/qxPnds) if you want to play with the code.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
int blankpos = 3, i, j;
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
        if ( j == blankpos )
            System.out.print(" ");
        else 
            System.out.print("*");
    }
    blankpos--;
    if ( blankpos < 1 )
        blankpos = 4;
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```